# Applying CSS Styling to Child Based on Ancestor Class

Tags: javascript, css

OK - I have a pretty basic page that I'm trying to keep as simple as possible.  I have a "theme selector" that chooses between a light and dark theme, and sets the body's class based on that, basically changing from white/black background/text.  I have boxes within that are a different background color that also need to change... is there a way to change the applied class of a child (perhaps many removed) based on the class of the body tag (or any ancestor for that matter) using CSS?

Simple demo:

```
<body class="dark">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="differentBG">THIS IS THE BOX I WANT TO CHANGE!</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I know I can use js (d3 is what I'm using) to apply a class to all of the children, but I want to keep as much in CSS as possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can base rules off of ancestor classes on the body tag as you would any other tag in your markup:

```
body.dark .differentBG {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

Our `differentBG` class will apply a black background *only* when the `<body>` has a class of "dark".

```
body.light .differentBG {
  background: white;
  color: black
}
```

Our `differentBG` class will apply a white background when `<body>` has a class of "light".

As an added bit of trivia, many developers use this very technique to setup their "JavaScript Disabled" styles:

```
body.nojs .dynamicElement {
  display: none;
}
```

And then use JavaScript to remove that class when the page loads. [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) also uses this method, though it adds classes to the `<html>` element to indicate what features the user agent supports.

Comment: Works like a charm - I knew this was simple but I couldn't find anything (at least the way I was phrasing the question).  I guess it comes down to a bit more complex understanding about how selectors work...